# How does Angular expose its field members to its templates?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

As the title states how exactly or even roughly does Angular 2+ actually expose it's objects properties to it's corresponding template i.e

```
class Example {
  readonly memberField = 'Example field';
}
```

to the HTML for interpolation?

```
<p> {{ memberField }} </p>
```

I suspect it's quite a complicated process but any form of guidance would be great.

Comment: [Angular's source code](https://github.com/angular/angular) is available on GitHub.

Comment: I'm not sure if this blog post will answer your question directly, but I think it contains related information that you may be interested in: https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/